# Folder disappears when service starts on CentOS

Tags: centos

I am currently facing an issue and running out of ideas. I have developed a systemctl service which is located at "/app". This service was installed via systemctl.

It was working fine, but due to a requirement, I have made a few changes to the installation script. The installation script detects a previous installation and make installation accordingly. I don't know if it is the reason, but the script uses "umount /app". The umount command was used after stopping the services. The reason why I included it it was because the installation was usually stating "folder or file busy" and failing the update (I tried other commands and none of it seemed to solve this problem).

After running the new installation script, I checked the "/app" folder and it indeed had the new version installed. After starting the service via "systemctl start SERVICENAME" I could check the status of the service was "Failed" and "ls /app" returns nothing. If I redo "umount /app" the contents of the folder re-appear but as soon as I start the service everything disappears.

I have tried to install the service in another folder (as a workaround) and it indeed works.

What may be exactly the issue?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have a filesystem mounted on /app.  When unmounted you're seeing the content of /app as they appear on the root disk.  When /app is mounted, you see the contents of the mounted filesystem.

Comment: How can I delete the filesystem being mounted?

Comment: First, determine if your application needs to be on a separate /app filesystem.  You really don't want to run out of space on your root partition due to your application filling it up.  Then take another look at your systemctl scripts and adjust accordingly. Hint: Unmounting /app to make the install script work smells a little fishy.